# Fibonacci in O log(N) with different seeds

Tags: c#, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity

This code is a translation from pseudo-code in a mathemathics wiki to resolve Fibonacci problem in O log(n).

The problem comes when you want to change the seeds of fibonacci (1,0), this is most mathematical question and complexity question than programatically...

So... Where to put A and B to start for example with seeds 5,6?

Thanks for your time!

```
public static BigInteger Fib(int A, int B, int n)
        {
            if (n <= 0)
                return 0;

            n = n - 1;
            _auxOne = 0;
            _auxTwo = 1;

            Matrix[0, 0] = _auxTwo; //a
            Matrix[0, 1] = _auxOne; //b
            Matrix[1, 0] = _auxOne; //c
            Matrix[1, 1] = _auxTwo + _auxOne; //d

            while (n > 0)
            {
                if (n % 2 != 0)
                {
                    _auxOne = Matrix[1, 1] * Matrix[0, 1] + Matrix[1, 0] * Matrix[0, 0]; //(db+ca)
                    _auxTwo = Matrix[1, 1] * (Matrix[0, 1] + Matrix[0, 0]) + Matrix[1, 0] * Matrix[0, 1]; //(d(b+a)+cb)
                    Matrix[0, 0] = _auxOne;
                    Matrix[0, 1] = _auxTwo;
                }
                _auxOne = BigInteger.Pow(Matrix[1, 0], 2) + BigInteger.Pow(Matrix[1, 1], 2); //(c²+d²)
                _auxTwo = Matrix[1, 1] * (2 * Matrix[1, 0] + Matrix[1, 1]); //(d*(2c+d))
                Matrix[1, 0] = _auxOne;
                Matrix[1, 1] = _auxTwo;

                n = n / 2;
            }
            return Matrix[0, 0] + Matrix[0, 1];
        }
```

Comment: I would assume you would put "different" values in place of the existing ones (but you didn't consider showing the code that calls what you have shown).

Comment: Fib(6,5,5) <== calculates the 5th fib number using the seeds 6,5)

Comment: `_auxOne = A; _auxTwo = B;` - or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Not so easy... @Corak

Comment: @Corak Seems it is the other way round: `_auxOne = B` , btw: you should declare them locally (_auxOne and _auxTwo)

Comment: @Fildor - ... or that. And why involve a matrix? Wouldn't it be easier (to read) to use variables `a, b, c, d` or *maybe* an array?

Comment: Can you provide the link to your *mathemathics wiki* article? The one I found would have a different set of initial matrix values, but I don't know whether it matters to the problem.

Comment: The comment was incorrect, the code works perfectly (for normal fibonacci solution(1,0))

Comment: Edited comment to reflect the (correct) code.

Comment: Yeah...its not that simple.Matrix exponentiation only works with initial seeds as 0,1. Its not that easy to just change seeds to get nth Fibonacci number

Comment: @Corak, you easy can find mathematical base on wikipedia.org in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form. Therefore, if you want to replace seed you need first fully filled matrix, in case with 5 and 6 it will be {11,6,6,5} and already this matrix, multiplied on { 1,1,1,0 } give us next Fibonacci number  {17,11,11,6}. So what we need 1)Calculate first matrix, filled with f1,f2 and f3  2)decrease n to 3 (or may be 2) and 3)call existing code

Comment: @vitalygolub - that *does* sound interesting. Would you like to write that actual code and put it as answer here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, as i wrote before in comments, actually we just need "normal" Fibonacci matrix to multiply to our modified matrix with seed, so one part of my code is mutation of existing OP code. I made  only 2 changes - i need whole matrix instead of calculation result and replaced BigInteger with Int64 to avoid additional references.

```
public static Int64 PerversationFib(int A, int B, int n) 
{
    if (n <= 0)
        return 0;

    if (n == 1)
        return A + B;
    else 
    {
        Int64[,] myMatrix = new Int64[2, 2] { { A , B }, { B, A+B} };
        Int64[,] fibMatrix = Fib(n);

        //a11·b11 + a12·b21
        return myMatrix[0, 0] * fibMatrix[0, 0] + myMatrix[0, 1] * fibMatrix[1, 0];  

    }

}

public static Int64[,] Fib( int n)
{
    if (n <= 0)
        return null;

    //n = n - 1;
   Int64 _auxOne = 0, _auxTwo = 1;
   Int64[,] Matrix = new Int64[2, 2]; 

   Matrix[0, 0] = _auxTwo; //a
   Matrix[0, 1] = _auxOne; //b
   Matrix[1, 0] = _auxOne; //c
   Matrix[1, 1] = _auxTwo + _auxOne; //d


    while (n > 0)
    {
        if (n % 2 != 0)
        {
            _auxOne = Matrix[1, 1] * Matrix[0, 1] + Matrix[1, 0] * Matrix[0, 0]; //(db+ca)
            _auxTwo = Matrix[1, 1] * (Matrix[0, 1] + Matrix[0, 0]) + Matrix[1, 0] * Matrix[0, 1]; //(d(b+a)+cb)
            Matrix[0, 0] = _auxOne;
            Matrix[0, 1] = _auxTwo;
        }
        _auxOne = Matrix[1, 0] * Matrix[1, 0]  +Matrix[1, 1]*Matrix[1,1]; //(c²+d²)
        _auxTwo = Matrix[1, 1] * (2 * Matrix[1, 0] + Matrix[1, 1]); //(d*(2c+d))
        Matrix[1, 0] = _auxOne;
        Matrix[1, 1] = _auxTwo;

        n = n / 2;
    }
    Matrix[1, 0] = Matrix[0, 1];
    Matrix[1, 1] = Matrix[0, 0]+Matrix[0,1] ;
    return Matrix;
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused with your base cases... wouldn't the result be `A` for `n=0` and `B` for `n=1`?

Comment: @grek40 Probably you are right, but if OP agree with you, he can easy  fix :-)